# How to change point set colour in R

Tags: r, colors

I have done a `PCA` in `R` and have graphed the results with a scatter plot.

I have 7 data variables and the last set of points come out as stock yellow. How can I make it so each set of points is a specific colour?

This is the code I have been using:

```
plot(clam.pca$x[,1], clam.pca$x[,2], pch = clam$Form.code,
     col = clam$Form.code, cex = .8, lty = "solid", lwd = 1,
     xlab = "Axis1", ylab = "Axis2", xlim = c(-0.2, 0.30))
```

Rory

Comment: Hi JordanD. The original question is British English. It's unfair to change the spelling one someone else's question to American English.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the colour to a variable using the generic plotting functions. You have to manually set what colour you want as a vector. So for example:

```
x<-seq(1:10)
y<-seq(1:10)
cols<-ifelse(group=="a","red","green")
plot(x,y,col=cols)
```

[image]